# How does Flask pass request variable through a decorator without me putting request as an argument?

Tags: python, flask, python-decorators

I've been learning about python decorators and I was wondering how flask passes the `request` variable into the function I decorate with the path.

```py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    print(request)
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

How is it that request exists? why don't I have to type in `def hello_world(request)` when writing the function?

When I try to make my own wrapper mimic that type of behavior like so

```py
def wrapper(function):
    def wrapped_item(*args, **kwargs):
        request = "yes"
        function(*args, **kwargs, request=request)
    return wrapped_item

@wrapper
def hello_world():
    print(request)

hello_world()
```

it results in an error `TypeError: hello_world() got an unexpected keyword argument 'request'`. However, when I put `def hello_world(request)`, it works as expected. So, **how do I get it to work with just having `def hello_world()`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flask uses Thread Local and this is how the "magic" happens. See https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/advanced_foreword/ and https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/local/ for more

Comment: Latest reference as of Flask 2.3.x
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/design/#thread-locals
and
https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/local

Answer (score 1):

It is a variable you import in

```
from flask import request
```

Your code example does not include it, but I am sure you have it in your file.